# Restore my Column Data using Entity Framework Code First Approach

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have mistakenly drop Column using Entity Framework Code First Approach and this column has most important data. No i do not know how to get back my column data. PLease help me in restoring Column data.

Comment: I'm sure you have a **recent backup** at hand, no??

Comment: If you're using any of the `DropDatabase......` initializers in your EF code-first approach, then you're out of luck - that data is gone for good. There's no magic way to bring it back, since EF **dropped** the database before re-creating it from its model when your model last changed (when you removed that column from your model).

Comment: @marc_s unfotunately no backup.however fortunately its not dropdb command rather its just column which i have lost....

Comment: I'm afraid your data is gone. When you drop a column you can only re-add the column, but of course, it's empty. :(

Comment: Yeah i know and i have actually lost it :'(